# How to ssh if not router administrator

Tags: ssh, vpn, router

I have my PC connected to the internet behind a router and want to connect via ssh to another PC online that is behind another router. My problem is that I am not the administrator neither routers and can not redirect port 22.  I Googled a bit and I understood that it could set a VPN between the two PCs but I have no idea if this is feasible, or how to do it

Comment: do some research in this area: http://alternativeto.net/software/no-ip/

Comment: How would that help me?

Comment: well, if you manage to install a program on each machine that uses a 3rd party to make a link between the machines that do not have public ip access, you could both bridge a ssh connection using that 3rd party.

Comment: like... hamachi?

Comment: i never used hamachi myself, not sure if they even released a linux version for it, but I know the concept behind it.. However you might find your the solution to your problem in the link i gave you, so look into it. Hope it helps. -- If it does help, i`m not going to post an official answer to your question so feel free to answer your question yourself.

Comment: Is port forwarding set up for the router (that has the computer you want to SSH into)?

Comment: It cannot be done if: ***1.*** The remote computer is on a LAN, ie. does not have a _Public IP_ address. ***2.*** You are unable to access the router/firewall providing that computer access to the internet, and open port 22, as well as forward requests on port ***x*** to port ***22*** on the _LAN IP_ of your remote computer, not even if you configure ssh on the remote computer to use a different port. The essentials here are ***Port Forwarding*** on the router if the assumptions made above are indeed accurate @Uriel

Comment: It would be way simpler to forward a port in the router which the *receiving* server is behind than to set up a VPN.  Thus the most straightforward and best solution to this is not Ubuntu-related.

Comment: i dont have currently to answer further but research reverse ssh connections

Comment: Reverse SSH connections still require at least one SSH server to be exposed to the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to the routers or changing the router it is going to be virtually impossible. Your router has a firewall. A firewall is a wall blocking ALL data. Rules are added to allow certain data. A port is a specif door in the wall, and a "port forward" is a door to a specific PC.

Without a port going to the target box there is NO way to send data to it (unless it requests the data first). So you cannot initiate a connection the PC. This applies to VPN, SSH, web or anything else.

edit:
PC1 -> Router1 -> Internet <- router 2 <- PC2  correct?

You should be able to use a service like splashtop or logmein. These have 3rd party servers that are involved in your connection. That is VERY different in terms of security from SSH, but if you don't care about a 3rd party such a thing should work.

Comment: mmm but i could have a vpn using hamachi on windows, there isn't any i could have a vlan  and use ssh that way?